# Python call and instance of powershell with variables

Tags: python, powershell

I want to be able to open an instance of powershell multiple times with different arguments.

I can open PowerShell in the same windows and run code using

```
subprocess.call(['powershell -file variables'])
```

I can also open an instance using

```
subprocess.call(['start PowerShell -file variables'])
```

but on this one the variables don't get sent to PowerShell?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `-file variables` is treated as arguments to `start`, not to `powershell`.

Comment: I fixed it finally after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(f'start C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -noexit -File TableauRefresh_CFO_email_Python.ps1 {S_username} {username} {times} {passw}', shell=True)
```

Using f formatted strings sent the variables to PowerShell while being able to open multiple instances of PowerShell using start PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

To open multiple instances of PowerShell with different arguments, use the following code:

```
import subprocess

script_arguments = ["script1.ps1", "script2.ps1", "script3.ps1"]

for argument in script_arguments:
    subprocess.call(['powershell', '-file', argument])
```